# Assert when including boost mutex header file in MFC dll

Tags: c++, boost, dll, mfc, assert

I have header version of boost 1_57. I would like to use feature of object_pool from  in my code.
However I see that if I just include this header file to any .cpp file that is compiled with my mfc dll project there is an assert inside dllinit.cpp when I'm running program that use this dll in debug mode:

```
void AFXAPI AfxCoreInitModule()
{
    ASSERT(AfxGetModuleState() != AfxGetAppModuleState());
    ...
}
```

I see that header includes also  and including it in my cpp file also cause that assert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue in Boost (incompatibility with MFC), in _pRawDllMain handling.

See here for possible solutions: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Thread-Solution-to-conflict-with-MFC-td3477977.html